# can't enable PDO in localhost apache php vesion 5.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't enable PDO in my localhost.

I have read the [php installation manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php#pdo.installation) and attempted to do the same thing, but it isn't working.

When i open phpinfo and search for pdo it appear that pdo_mysql is not enabled, as shown in the below image.

[image]

I uncommented all pdo extension in php.ini and that didn't help.

I also searched for the pdo.dll in my extension and found it.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: "it's not working" is too vague to getting help. What error you have? BTW, have you set the `pdo_mysql.default_socket` in php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image of your phpinfo it's only showing sqllite and mysql is missing.

In PHP 5.2 I believe PDO is not available under default compile so you'll need to make sure it's actually compiled into PHP by adding --with-pdo-mysql into your compile script or if available via your webhosting panel somewhere. Personally I'd recommend having your PHP version updated to a secure version but as always you have to make sure any existing code is compatible.